# How to simulate an NTM using a DTM?

Tags: turing-machines, nondeterminism

I've seen questions about how an NTM could simulate a DTM and this seems pretty straightforward to me. However, my text book says you can also simulate an NTM using a DTM.

How would this work? I'm especially curious on how to define the transitions, since in the DTM, each transition would have to be deterministic.

Comment: Would you be able to program it in a normal programming language?

Comment: Ye,s I'd probably use BFS and "step through" the different programs one at a time (or $n$ steps at a time if using iterative deepening). D.W. gave the term I was looking for though. I didn't know this form of programming could be generalized like that (or at least didn't think of it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [dovetailing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dovetailing_(computer_science)) to simulate all possible execution paths of the NTM.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks!